# Windows Phone App (web app)

Tags: windows-phone-8, web-applications

Is it possible to create a windows phone app which could display a web page in compatibility mode (IE 8)?

- using Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a windows phone app which could display a web
>   page in compatibility mode (IE 8)?
>
> using Visual Studio

yes it is.

It's impossible to teach someone in this type of setting.
I suggest you look at the following links:

Easier-
[Windows Phone 8 Development for Absolute Beginners](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners)
Harder-
[Building Apps for Windows Phone 8 Jump Start: (01a) Introducing Windows Phone 8 Development Part 1](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-01a-Introducing-Windows-Phone-8-Development-Part-1)
Windows 10 -
[Get started with Windows apps](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted)

You need to understand that windows phone app development has changed for windows 10 from windows 8. Windows phones and pcs running on windows 10 share the same operating system.
[Developers: Prepare for universal app development in Windows 10](http://blogs.microsoft.com/firehose/2014/12/18/developers-prepare-for-universal-app-development-in-windows-10/)

You have a lot of work ahead of you. I suggest you start and when you have a specific problem you can post your code and ask it here. Your question here is really not suitable for this site.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How? I mean can you guide me with the basic steps or exact procedure? Can we achieve the same on Android?

Comment: Thanks :) I will go through all the links you mentioned. Thanks for the valuable info.  I understand, I need to start things and do a lot of experimentation. Looking forward to post some specific questions when I am stuck. Excited to learn something new, thanks a lot!